# When delete [] pointer works, why can't you get the size of the array pointed to?

Tags: c++

A common way to use a heap-allocated array is:

```
SomeType * arr = new SomeType[15454];
//... somewhere else 
delete [] arr;
```

In order to do `delete [] arr` the C runtime has to know the length of the memory buffer associated with the pointer. Am I right?

So in principle it should be possible to access the information somehow? Could it be accessed using some library? I'm just wondering. I understand that it is not a core part of the language so it would be platform dependent.

Comment: It is stored somewhere in an implementation defined way. If you really need it, use `std::vector<double> arr{15454};` and  `arr.size()`.

Comment: Try this with gcc: `std::cout << ((long*)new int[50])[-1];` - you should get something a little over `200` (`50` `int`s, at `4` bytes each, plus some padding). Of coruse, do not depend on this...

Comment: @manni66 your example creates 1 element with the value `15454`: http://ideone.com/mLWAEg

Comment: @mch you are right - the vector uniform initialisation fiasco ;). Should be `std::vector<double> arr(15454);`

Comment: If it's important to keep track of the size of an array allocated on the free store, use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get it right.  The information is there.  But there is no standard way of obtaining it.

If you are using windows, there is an `_msize()` method, which might give you the size of the memory block, though it may not necessarily be accurate.  (The reported memory block size may be rounded up to the closest larger alignment point.)  See [MSDN -
 _msize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/msize)

If this is something that you really must have, you can try your luck with overriding `new`, allocating a slightly larger memory block, storing its size in the beginning, and returning a pointer to the byte after the size.  Then you can write your own `msize()` which returns that size.  Of course you will need to also override `delete`.  But it is too much hassle, and it is best to avoid it if you can.  If that way you go, only pain will you find.

Comment: Keep in mind: there are two hidden values. The number of bytes allocated `_msize`, and the number of objects constructed. `struct A{char b; ~A(){std::cout<<'c';}}; delete[] new A[5];` Here, the library probably allocates ~32 bytes, but also has to keep track that there's only 5 objects there, so it knows now many destructors to call.

Answer (score 5):

The information exists. Unfortunately, the standart does not specify how dynamic memory should be allocated, nor how the size of the allocated block could be extracted.

That mean that each implementation can do what it wants. Classical ways are:

- an allocation table storing all allocated/free blocks with their begin and size - simple to implement except for searches in the table
- reserved zones before and after dynamically allocated memory zones - the implementation actually allocates zones consisting in: preamble - dynamic_memory  - postamble. The preamble/postamble contains linking informations to other *zones*, size and status. At deallocation time, the preamble/postamble integrity can be controlled to optionnaly emit a warning for probable memory overwrite. The preamble is the memory preceding the dynamic memory presented to the program.

But as nothing is specified, you will have to dig in the internals of your implementation. Normally reading the source of malloc/free is the best source of information.

Answer (score -6):

The truth is `delete[]` does not know *the exact size* of an array you have allocated, but it knows how much memory was allocated with the corresponding call to `new[]`. Often no excess memory is allocated, so the two numbers match. However, you cannot rely on it. This is not part of the standard because there is no reliable way of knowing the size of a dynamically allocated array.

Comment: `delete[]` needs to be able to call the destructor for each object in the array. So it needs to know how many objects are stored at some level.

Comment: @juanchopanza, I've seen this misconception many times. Even if certain compilers act in such a way, there is no requirement to store the requested allocation size. Compare that to the implementation of a c-string. It has a certain size, however, it is not directly stored anywhere.

Comment: @VolodymyrLashko *cstrings* allocated with `malloc` didn't need to know their size because `C` neve calls destructors. That's different if you allocate memory with `new`, then the allocation system has to know how many destructors to call. It is a basic difference between `malloc` and `new`.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was so much downvoted and how it is different from that of @Mike Nakis. Anyway, thanks @Galik for pointing out the difference between malloc and new. So malloc is faster for primitive types like `double[]` ?

Comment: @ProkopHapala Well for primitive types the constructor does nothing so it is unlikely to be slower. But because non-primitive types require the book keeping it has to be there in some form.

Comment: @VolodymyrLashko What misconception? There isn't one in my comment, but maybe you're referring to something else.

Comment: @juanchopanza In some ABIs, there is no "cookie" for the size (on the C++ level) if the type is trivially destructible.

Comment: @T.C. Wonderful. And if it is not?

Comment: @juanchopanza if it is not, and the `new[]` isn't the non-allocating placement array new, then the ABI at issue will store a cookie. Regardless, of course you are right that if it actually needs to call the destructors it has to stash the information somewhere.